# set an array with useState doesn't change the result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a list of data like this:

```
data = [
  {
    id:1,
    name: "boo"
  },
  {
    id:1,
    name: "boo"
  }
]
```

I initialize it with react *UseState* like follows:

```
const [items, setItems] = useState(data)
```

And I map this in my react code and visualize them.

If I want to delete one I do it with the following function:

```
  const deleteItem = async (id) => {
    console.log('BEFORE- - - ->', items);
    // this functions calls an api to delete the item
    await deleteItem({ id });
    setItems((oldItems) =>
      oldItems.filter(({ id }) => id !== commentId)
    );
    console.log('AFTER- - - ->', items);
  };
```

Graphically the component with the deleted item disappears, but actually the second *console.log* prints the same thing as the first log. In this case if I delete the element with *id:1* I will get the same log while I see graphically that the element disappears. This causes a problem with indexing if I want to delete more than one item.

Which do you think is the problem? has I to do it into one useEffect?

Comment: console.log right after a setState call doesn't log the updated result. The newly set value won't be available until the next render cycle

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting state is an asynchronous action.  If you put a console outside of that function, on the next re-render you will see your state updated correctly (just like you've seen your item disappear visually).

Answer (score 1):

This happens because setState is asynchronous so the state really changes after you console.log